# How does core triggers cleanup of expired sessions in database?

Tags: 8, sessions

core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php defines a method (gc()) to clear expired sessions from the database (sessions table)

when is that triggered ? is there a way to trigger it from the interface ?

i know i can just truncate sessions manually or with a cron or a custom drush command..., but i wonder how does core uses it and what triggers it by default

Thanks

Comment: I can't say 100% without looking into it fully but my likely guess is part of a cron run, probably by system_cron function in the system.module

Comment: looked at system_cron() but it doesn't seem to do so. at least not directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> #### Configuring Garbage Collection
>
> When a session opens, PHP will call the `gc` handler randomly
>   according to the probability set by `session.gc_probability` /
>   `session.gc_divisor`. For example if these were set to 5/100
>   respectively, it would mean a probability of 5%. Similarly, 3/4 would
>   mean a 3 in 4 chance of being called, i.e. 75%.
>
> If the garbage collection handler is invoked, PHP will pass the value
>   stored in the **php.ini** directive `session.gc_maxlifetime`. The
>   meaning in this context is that any stored session that was saved more
>   than `gc_maxlifetime` ago should be deleted. This allows one to expire
>   records based on idle time.
>
> However, some operating systems (e.g. Debian) do their own session
>   handling and set the `session.gc_probability` variable to 0 to stop
>   PHP doing garbage collection. That's why Symfony now overwrites this
>   value to 1.
>
> If you wish to use the original value set in your **php.ini**, add the
>   following configuration:
>
> ```
> # config/packages/framework.yaml
> framework:
>     session:
>         gc_probability: null
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [Symphony's official docs on Configuring Sessions and Save Handlers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)</sub>

In Drupal this is seen in /sites/default/**default.settings.php**

```
/**
 * Some distributions of Linux (most notably Debian) ship their PHP
 * installations with garbage collection (gc) disabled. Since Drupal depends on
 * PHP's garbage collection for clearing sessions, ensure that garbage
 * collection occurs by using the most common settings.
 */
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
```

Since the above "most common settings" is set to 1/100, Garbage Collection would run 1% of the time.

Now, as per the code comment, I presume this does not get put into settings.php when it gets auto-generated if your distribution has one already set one in one of its files as I don't see this in my settings.php

You can also set this in **services.yml** as [seen in this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/215632/27710).

---

### In Conclusion

Note that while Drupal is built on top of Symphony, it does not rely on Symphony for this. I just quoted their nice explanation from their documentation.

We learned that PHP automatically calls this `gc()` method every `session.gc_probability/session.gc_divisor` % of the time and if you look at PHP docs on SessionHandler.

> **SessionHandler** is a special class that can be used to expose the
>   current internal PHP session save handler by inheritance. There are
>   seven methods which wrap the seven internal session save handler
>   callbacks (open, close, read, write, destroy, gc and create_sid).
>
> <sub>Source: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php</sub>

core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/**SessionHandler.php**

```
/**
 * Default session handler.
 */

class SessionHandler extends AbstractProxy implements \SessionHandlerInterface { ...

 /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function gc($lifetime) {
    // Be sure to adjust 'php_value session.gc_maxlifetime' to a large enough
    // value. For example, if you want user sessions to stay in your database
    // for three weeks before deleting them, you need to set gc_maxlifetime
    // to '1814400'. At that value, only after a user doesn't log in after
    // three weeks (1814400 seconds) will his/her session be removed.
    $this->connection->delete('sessions')
      ->condition('timestamp', REQUEST_TIME - $lifetime, '<')
      ->execute();
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: `Now, as per the code comment, I presume this does not get put into settings.php when it gets auto-generated if your distribution has one already set >one in one of its files as I don't see this in my settings.php`   
Actually this is in default.services.yml file in the site folder.

Comment: i configured gc_probability and gc_divisor to 100 (both). i also configured gc_maxlifetime to 20  in default.services.yml and in php.ini (just to be sure)  
I still have very old sessions in sessions table meaning that the ->gc() method wasn't fired event after login/logout.  
i still don't know how this can be executed by Drupal core . is the execution order missed between php and symfony or between symfony and Drupal or something else i still ignore

Comment: First of all, if you want to put it in the yml file, copy default.services.yml and rename it services.yml; otherwise, when you update core you will lose your changes.

Comment: Second, most importantly, I am sure your `gc` method is running at some point. If you look carefully what Drupal's `gc()` method does (which is exactly why I included it in my answer) and if you read the `gc` code comments, it checks against if `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime` have passed since the last time the user has logged in. If your `php_value 
 session.gc_maxlifetime` is set to 3 weeks or a year, the old sessions will not be getting deleted any time soon no matter how many times `gc` runs

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/215632/27710) which sets the max life time.