# Setting SameSite=None on a session cookie

Tags: 9, cookies

I have a custom endpoint which stores a value in a session cookie, using this code:

```
$session = $this->request->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('test.email', $data['email']);
```

I'm calling this endpoint from a decoupled frontend.

This works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it looks like the session cookie is being blocked because SameSite is set to Lax. How would I set SameSite to be None? Ideally I only want to do that for this cookie, not all cookies.

Comment: I don't think you can do so because the Session service has only one configuration for samesite. Have you considered setting a specific cookie rather than using the session cookie? Also, FWIW, Chrome assumes "Lax" if samesite is unset.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at switching to a custom cookie, I guess I'll need to store the data in user data with an expiry instead of session storage

Comment: Actually I can't use user data, this is an anonymous session

Comment: Local storage and cookies are different things.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you wrote. Any cookie can have an expiry, which should work.

Comment: Yep, but I need to store some data on the server side too. I can't store it in session data or in the tempStore because those use session cookies. I can't store it in userData because it's an anonymous session. Hopefully I don't have to define my own schema for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the session cookie settings in services.yml. See [How do I set the cookie lifetime?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215622/how-do-i-set-the-cookie-lifetime)

This is not only possible for the default parameters defined by Drupal but for any parameter listed in the PHP docs:

https://www.php.net/session.configuration

So you can add SameSite=None to the session storage options:

*sites/default/services.yml*

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000
    cookie_lifetime: 2000000
    sid_length: 48
    sid_bits_per_character: 6
    cookie_samesite: none
```

These options only apply to the session cookie, not to any cookie set by your site. To change the options dynamically see [How do I dynamically change cookie_lifetime?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/279292/how-do-i-dynamically-change-cookie-lifetime)